# Angular route authorization & security

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I just learned about the routing mechanics and the routing guards to provide authorization to access routes.
As a front end framework, this guard mechanic seems insufficient to me to secure my web server, unless I'm failing to understand something, as the restricted 'pages' (routes) are also downloaded during the first connection. What would be the best practice to protect, say, a /admin route ?

Answer (score 0):

"The restricted pages are also downloaded during first connection". This is not true. Only if your guard interface return true the route will even be loaded.

You can use the CanActivate to check before resolving route.

Example from [here](https://angular.io/guide/router):

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {
    console.log('AuthGuard#canActivate called');
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "loaded", do you mean loaded in the DOM (from JavaScript which is already downloaded), or do you mean downloaded from the server ?

Comment: Loaded into DOM, guard mechanic alone won't prevent app scripts from downloading. That has to be done using lazy-loading. Webpack is most popular way of doing this now. 
Check [link](https://medium.com/walkme-engineering/how-and-when-not-to-use-webpack-for-lazy-loading-bef9d37c42c1)

Comment: Well in that case that was the point of my question. If the user already has downloaded the info (whether it's in JavaScript form or otherwise) then it's unsafe to rely on this mechanism to prevent access to sensitive information. Does webpack provide this functionality?